# Convex sets in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

First I should introduce some definitions and then state my question.

For a metric space $(X,d)$ and points $x,y\in X$ the interval $[x,y]$ is defined by $$[x,y]:=\{z\in X\,|\,d(x,y)=d(x,z)+d(z,y)\}$$

A set $C\subseteq X$ is said to be convex if $[x,y]\subseteq C$ for all $x,y\in C$

An open ball is any set $B(x,r)\subseteq X$ that satisfies $$B(x,r)=\{y\in X\,|\,d(x,y)<r\}$$
for some fixed point $x\in X$ and real number $r>0$

A closed ball is any set $\overline{B(x,r)}\subseteq X$ that satisfies $$\overline{B(x,r)}=\{y\in X\,|\,d(x,y)\leq r\}$$
for some fixed point $x\in X$ and real number $r>0$

My question is: Are all open balls and closed balls convex in any metric space?

Comment: A little remark : this definition of convexity in general metric spaces can be uninteresting in certain spaces where $[x,y]$ can be reduced to the two endpoints $x$ and $y$...

Comment: @JeanMarie Can it? Take $\mathbb R$ with the standard metric. Take $x=0,y=2$. Then $d(0,2) = 2 = 1 + 1 =d(0,1)+d(1, 2)$, so $1\in [0,2]$...

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is a good metric space... You can have many weird metric spaces...

Answer (score 1):

No. I think the smallest example is $4$ points (one for center, two for ends of segment, one for internal):

$d(O, x) = d(O, y) = 1$

$d(x, y) = 1.5$

$d(O, z) = 1.1$

$d(x, z) = d(y, z) = 0.75$

Then $\{O, x, y\}$ is both open and closed ball with center in $O$ and radius $1.05$, but it's not convex.

Comment: the sum of two elements in {1,1.5,1.1,0.75} produces the set {2,2.5,2.1,1.75,3,2.6,2.25,2.2,1.85} which shares no elements with {1,1.5,1.1,0.75}, therefore no sum of the distances of two different points can give the distance between any two other different points, and so any point can only be in the intervals where it is an endpoint, so it is convex

Comment: $z \in [x, y]$, as $d(x, y) = 1.5 = 0.75 + 0.75 = d(x, z) + d(z, y)$.

Comment: oh yeah sorry XD, thank you